# In C#, How can I know when the assignment operator (=) will copy the value or memory address (reference)?

Tags: c#

For example, after this code runs, what does list2 contain, and how can I be confident in that?

```
List<SomeClass> list1 = new List<SomeClass>();
List<SomeClass> list2 = new List<SomeClass>();

SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(); // assume assignment operator (=) 
                                // is defined for this class

list1.Add(sc);
list2.Add(new SomeClass());
list2[0] = list1[0];
list1.RemoveAt(0);
```

Comment: Is there even any type for which `=` is not defined?

Comment: Have you run this code? If you have, what did `list2` contain? What did you expect it to contain? Was the result different to what you expected?

Comment: @CharlesBretana The issue is deeper than that: the assignment operator **cannot** be overloaded. Therefore, it *is* defined for all types - as per the language specification.

Comment: @dcastro,  ahhh yes you're right, I forgot that... although now that you've reminded me of that, I would argue that the issue is not deep at all, it is, in effect, moot.   I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 4):

The `=` operator copies `struct` types by value, and `class` types by reference.

C# does not allow overriding the `=` operator, as may be done in C++.

Assuming your are coming from a C++ perspective, consider that in C++ the value/reference semantics of memory is determined by the user of a type, whereas in C# it is the designer of the type that decides.

So assuming `SomeClass` is a `class` as the name suggests, when your example code completes, `list2` will contain `sc` and the anonymous instance created for `list2` is unreachable and will be garbage collected.

Also the syntax of `list1.RemoveAt[0]` is incorrect. You must use `()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: No, it does *not* copy reference types by reference.  The assignment operator *always* copies the *value* of the expression on the right into the variable on the left.  The value of the expression on the right, for a reference type, simply happens to be a reference to another value.  That reference is still copied by value, not by reference.  Copying a reference by reference would be something very different.

Comment: @Servy, I use the word reference in place of pointer. The `=` operator copies the reference for reference types, and the value of value types.

Comment: You state that it is copied *by* reference.  Not that it is copying *a* reference.  The two are *radically* different.  One is right, and one is wrong.  The one that you posted is wrong.

Comment: Syntax corrected. What do you mean when you say list2 would contain sc? Do you mean that it would "point" to it, or it would contain a duplicate of the data in the sc instance?

Comment: Think of it like this. You call `new` twice, so you have two instances of the class. An instance of a class only ever exists when `new` is called (apart from some rare cases.) I count two `new` calls in your code, so there are two instances. `list2` must therefore contain a reference (pointer) to `sc`. The reference is copied from `list1[0]` in your second-last line. You can test this with the code `ReferenceEquals(sc, list2[0])` which will return `true`.

Answer (score 3):

The `=` operator applied to value types will copy the one value to the variable. On all other (reference types) it will 'copy' the memory address.

The full list of value types (source [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx)):

- bool
- byte
- char
- decimal
- double
- enum
- float
- int
- long
- sbyte
- short
- struct
- uint
- ulong
- ushort

About the `=` operator (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)):

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand operand and returns the value as its result. The operands must be of the same type (or the right-hand operand must be implicitly convertible to the type of the left-hand operand).

Comment: What about `struct`s?

Comment: It is in the value type list. See above.

Comment: It is not possible to create a full list of value types as isers may create their own as custom `struct`s.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: It will always remain a `struct`. It will never become a `class`.

Comment: @DrewNoakes User defined structs are on his list of types...(4th from the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right   there class and struct,sow  tow classes will are depended that mean if you have

```
List<SomeClass> list1 = new List<SomeClass>();
List<SomeClass> list2 = new List<SomeClass>();
```

if you make change list1,the list2 is gonna change to,list2  point the same class.

But if you use struck it will not chage because they undepended and do not poin to the same place.

Comment: @Drew Noakes explained this better wile i was typing my answer))